# How to export fbx with textures from Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have downloaded a Unity asset which included lots of 3d models with textures/materials etc.

I wanted to share one of those objects with an artist, so that they can create a new model on top of that model, so I exported the fbx from Unity using one of the Unity fbx exporter assets.

However, the model was exported without any textures and so it looked pretty much white as a whole. Therefore, the artist cannot really work on a model that includes textures and also send me back the finished work with those textures.

I am wondering, is there a way to actually export everything with the fbx 
from Unity ? Thanks !

Comment: Just send the textures with the model to the artist. Put the model iwht its textures in the-same folder and send. All the artist has to do is create new material and then plug the correct textures to the right spot. Just name them properly.

Comment: so just sending the asset files would be enough ? Wonder if they are somehow tied to my account or if they would not be easy for the artist to work with. It's like fbx files along with prefabs

Comment: I did not say you should send Asset files. I said you should send the fbx file(.fbx) with the textures(.png,  jpg...). That's all the artist should need, Nothing more and they are not tied to any account. If you need to combine all objects into a scene and want the artist to work in that scene, it is better to do this in a 3D modeling software instead of Unity or the artist will have to learn Unity to do it in Unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your material in the source package, make sure there is a baked texture in the diffuse slot

Assign your other baked textures to the spec, normal and others

Check embed textures at export

Check 'import materials: by material name' is selected for your imported model (in the inspector)

Where possible use a portable file format like FBX and follow these guidelines.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/material-texture-faq.244786/ http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/HOWTO-exportFBX.html

Comment: URL is down unfortunately

Comment: I am trying this in with the latest Blender and Unity and it doesn't seem to work. There seems to be no "Import Materials: by material name" option in the latest recommended Unity (2020.3.16f1). Has something changed?

Comment: @Locksleyu You can choose "import via MaterialDescription" and then click `Extract Materials/Textures` button.